# asp.net calendar control header is seperated from calendar

Tags: calendar, controls

I have a web form with buttons and other controls including a calendar control and the month header of the calendar control is separated from the days. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: When I drag a calendar to a web form without a master page the calendar header is attached. When I drag a calendar to a web form with a master page the calendar header is not attached. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by creating a new web form project and copying the generated .css files into my project and it fixed it.